# docker-compose wait for startup script of PostgreSQL to finish before starting local Dockerfile's container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file which specifies that the `backend` service should wait until the `postgres` service is healthy before starting the `backend` service. Apparently, `postgres` service is already healthy even if it is still running its startup script.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  backend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}"
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB}"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
volumes:
  data:
```

I am mounting a startup script that runs for quite a while in the `./initdb.d` file. The startup script will populate the DB with 1M rows. It seems like when the startup scripts are running, the `backend` service can't connect to `postgres`. Right now, my best solution is simply to add `restart: on-failure:5` to wait for the startup scripts to finish. Is there a more robust way to achieve this though?

Comment: The canonical question on this topic is [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y); any of the approaches that depend on a TCP connection from another container won't have this problem.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR; add `-h 127.0.0.1` to your pg_isready arguments.

You can see in the entrypoint for the container (/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh) that it starts postgres temporarily without network access while it runs the init.d parts.

pg_isready by default connects to postgres over a unix socket which is available, so changing this to use tcp mimics the external network access to the container which achieves the desired effect.

Comment: This was super helpful, thank you! For those wanting more detail, here's [the code](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/44ef8b226a40f86cf9df3f9299067db6779a3aa3/docker-entrypoint.sh#L261-L276) where they start up the server without binding the external port. That's why this answer, indeed, works.